# Counting Active Connections

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I wanted to know what would be the best way to get a count of all the active connections per user in a DB setup like this. Only the first two groups should be used in the query. The Result Set is what I would like the output of the query to look like.

[image]

One thing to keep in mind is that it is possible that a Users record might have been deleted and not reflected in the Connections table. The result set should only count connections with other accounts that are still in the users table. I would also like to sort the results by the Count.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Users.UserId,count(*) Count
FROM ConnectionsTable
 JOIN Users  ON ( Users.UserId = Requestor OR Users.UserId = Requestee) 
GROUP BY Users.UserId
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Comment: The user should be counted whether they are the requestor or requestee

Comment: added an or on the join. that should do it

Comment: Sorry ResultSet is what I would like the output of the query to look like. It's not a third table. Only the first two table should be used in the query.

Comment: removed the resultset from the query. i assumed you wanted the highest count sorted to the top. If not remove the DESC

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I update query to add the Group By section. Thank you

Comment: actually this does not account for the Connections records where the Users record have been deleted. For instance if Tom is deleted form the Users table Both Sam and Frank should have one less in the result set.

Comment: the result should only show users who exist in both tables since its a join. a left join would show regardless. Maybe i am not understanding what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT source.UserId, COUNT(*) as [Count]
FROM
(
  (
    SELECT Requestor as UserID
    FROM Connections
  )
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT Requestee as UserID
    FROM Connections
  )
) source
WHERE Exists (SELECT top 1 1 FROM Users us WHERE us.UserId = source.UserId)
GROUP BY source.UserId
```